# Laço de repetição em C++

Tags: c++, variáveis, for

Boa noite, meus amigos!

Estou iniciando no curso de ADS e fiquei com uma dúvida. Preciso criar um laço de repetição para 50 alunos coletando 4 notas de 4 provas, e ao final, apresentar um relatório com as notas de cada um dos indivíduos e a geral média da turma. Bom, já estreguei o trabalho (para aqueles que estão pensando que eu quero enganar o professor e, por tabela me enganar junto rs. Consegui fazer a média, todavia, não consegui declarar as notas individuais :(... Na minha lógica, pra fazer isto, teria que criar uma var pra cada um dos estudantes e guardar os resultados lá, mas isso daria um trabalho desnecessário e não consegui pensar em outra forma. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer? Utilizo o livro Linguagem C do Damas e também não consegui achar nada parecido.

Meu código só com a media geral:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char q1,q2,q3,q4;
    int alunos,totalunos,notaturma,notaq1,notaq2,notaq3,notaq4;
    float media;
    for (alunos=1;alunos<=2;alunos++)
    {
        printf("\nSua resposta da questao 1: "); scanf(" %c",&q1);
        printf("\nSua resposta da questao 2: "); scanf(" %c",&q2);
        printf("\nSua resposta da questao 3: "); scanf(" %c",&q3);
        printf("\nSua resposta da questao 4: "); scanf(" %c",&q4);
        
        if (q1=='A')
        notaq1=notaq1+2;
        if(q2=='C')
        notaq2=notaq2+2;
        if(q3=='A')
        notaq3=notaq3+2;
        if(q4=='C')
        notaq4=notaq4=2;
        totalunos++; //Coletará o total de alunos para ser usado no calculo da média de notas//
        
    }
    notaturma=notaq1+notaq2+notaq3+notaq4;
    totalunos=totalunos-1; //Retirei um pois estava sendo contato um aluno a mais//
    media=notaturma/totalunos;
    printf("\n%2.f E A MEDIA DA TURMA",media);

}
```

Comment: Note que definir variáveis individuais para cada nota de cada um dos 50 alunos é algo improdutivo e inviável, para isso utilizamos array. Para este caso podemos declarar `char nota[50][4];` onde cada linha deste array representa um aluno e cada coluna o conceito de uma prova. O que você não explicou é quais são os conceitos possíveis e como você transforma o conceito em uma nota para o cálculo da média. Talvez `float nota[50]4];` seja mais adequado para o cálculo da média e cada nota poderia facilmente ser transformado em um conceito considerando faixas de valores.

Comment: Perfeito! A professora não havia dado esse conceito, mas cobrou kkkkkkkkkkkkk Muito obrigado mesmo, vou pesquisar sobre array.

Answer (score 2):

**Olá boa noite, segue minha resolução para seu problema, único diferencial é que usei a linguagem C++ para a resolução, se conseguir deixar o exercício em amostra conseguirei te ajudar melhor, (no momento foi oque eu consegui extrair do seu enunciado). Caso queira testar o codigo, deixarei o link da IDE online REPL C++ para você testar o código :)
https://repl.it/languages/cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char notasAlunos[50][4];
    float notaGeralTurma = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << "A " << j+1 << "° do aluno: ";
            cin >> notasAlunos[i][j];
                
            if (notasAlunos[i][j] == 'A' || 'a' ||'C' || 'c')
                notaGeralTurma += 2;
        }
    }
    
    cout << "A media da turma é: " << notaGeralTurma / 50 << endl;
    
    cout << "As notas lidas foram :" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << notasAlunos[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Em C++ tem um monte de regras e padrões de codificação

1 - Criar uma estrutura e sobrescrever `<<` e `>>`

```
struct respostas : array<char, N_QUESTOES> {
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const respostas& n ) {
       return o << "Nota do aluno: " << string_view(n.begin(), n.end());
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& i, respostas& n ) {
       for ( auto& el : n ) 
          i >> el;
       return i;
    }
};
```

2 - Evitar loops for/while no seu código, nesse caso á melhor encapsular os loops criando um algoritmo genérico  para verificar quantos matches dois containers tem e usá-lo para ver quantos pontos cada aluno fez:

```
template<typename It1, typename It2>
int matches(It1 first, It1 last, It2 first2) {
    int result = 0;
    while( first != last ) {
        if ( *first++ == *first2++ ) {
            ++result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

3 - E o "core" do programa é uma chamada ao algoritmo `accumulate` deixando evidente que você está fazendo algum tipo de totalização nos elementos.

```
auto acertos = accumulate( respostasDosAlunos.begin(), respostasDosAlunos.end(), 0, [&in, &gabarito](auto result, auto& resp){
    cout << "\nNota do aluno: ";
    in >> resp;
    return result + matches(resp.begin(), resp.end(), gabarito.begin());
});
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wc1MWo